# how to get last 9 months data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am working on a stored proc and need last 9 months data. Need a syntax Which will automatically deletes the oldest data when new data will be added to the table(Latest 9 months data).

That syntax is gonna be used in Select Syntax.

I have used

```
select * from tablename t
left outer join calendartable r on
t.fiscal_month=r.fiscal_month
where t.date > dateadd(m,-9,date)
```

I know it is wrong. Could you guys please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Generally it's a good idea to format your code using code tags, and to include an idea of your table structure.

Comment: I know its easy for you guys also for better understanding..

Comment: Small modification to my question, if we have a date then below answers will work. But what about if we have [Fiscal_Month] instead of [Date]. Example for [Fiscal_Month] is like this '2012M03','2011M05', etc..then the dateadd(m,-9,date) syntax will not work out there.. what else we can do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want [GETDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) to calculate the nine month boundary from now:

```
where t.date >= dateadd(m,-9, GETDATE())
```

Beware that if t.date is a date and time field not just date you'll see odd behaviour on the nine-month boundary unless you also round away the time before the comparison.

Or if you're comparing it against another value e.g. the date of the inserted record in your trigger then what you've got is probably OK, e.g. something like

```
declare @latest date
select @latest = inserted.date
delete from ... where t.date < dateadd(m, -9, @latest)
```

although I suggest you actually archive off the data, not delete it.

---

Since you've clarified you want whole months, i.e. 9 months from the end of last month, you could use

```
declare @today date;
declare @firstOfMonth date;
declare @nineMonthsAgo date;
set @today = GETDATE();
set @firstOfMonth = DATEADD(d, 1-DAY(@today), @today);
set @nineMonthsAgo = DATEADD(m, -9, @firstOfMonth);

... WHERE date >= @nineMonthsAgo AND date < @firstOfMonth
```

Comment: Thanks for replying... I see that you have put getdate() on top.. it is good if we need the data from today's date.. What if we want the data from last month May 31st 2011..

Answer (score 1):

seems like it's pretty close. Do you need 9 months from right now, or 9 months from a given date?

how about:

```
declare @date datetime

set @date = dateadd(m, -9, getdate()) -- 9 months from right now

select * 
from tablename t
  left outer join calendartable r 
   on t.fiscal_month=r.fiscal_month
where t.date > @date
```

Comment: the data in the table is uploaded on 15th of every month and I need to pull the data which show 9 months from the end of the last month. Suppose today is 06/14/11 and tomorrow the data is going to be uploaded and they need the data from Sep 1st 2010 till May 31st 2011. Hope you understand my question now.

Answer (score 1):

If You need to delete the data when new data is added, you will need to do it in a trigger. And the sintax inside the trigger would be like this.

```
DELETE t
FROM 
tablename t
left outer join calendartable r on
t.fiscal_month=r.fiscal_month
where datediff(month, t.date, GETDATE()) > 9
```

And the select to retrieve your data will be similar.

```
select * from tablename t
left outer join calendartable r on
t.fiscal_month=r.fiscal_month
where datediff(month, t.date, GETDATE()) < 9
```